# Android app using Monodroid unable to get external program to correctly open file

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to get external applications to open different file types determined at runtime. From everything I've looked at I feel I'm doing it right but none of the programs open the files correctly. For Astro using text files it shows this error: java.lang.illegalargumentexception invalid uri used for observer. Basically it appears not to have gotten the right file location. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();

  String attachmentPath = appManager.getAttachmentPath(plexState.getActiveBrain().getGuid(), attachment.getId(), attachment.getType());

  webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (object sender, System.Net.DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs eventArgs) =>
  {
    notificationManager.hidePopup();

    if ((eventArgs.Cancelled == false) && (eventArgs.Error == null))
    {
      byte[] fileBytes = eventArgs.Result;

      Java.IO.File attachmentFile = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads), attachment.getName());
      System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(attachmentFile.AbsolutePath, fileBytes);

      // Get MIME type
      String extension = MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(attachmentFile.AbsolutePath);
      String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);

      Logger.console("File exists: " + attachmentFile.Exists()); // Shows true.

      intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(attachmentFile));
      intent.SetType(mimeType);

      // Check if any application can open the given MIME type. Otherwise show notice to user
      PackageManager packageManager = Activity.PackageManager;
      IList<ResolveInfo> resolversList = packageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

      if (resolversList.Count > 0)
      {
        Activity.StartActivity(intent);
      }
      else
      {
        Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Unable to find for ext...", ToastLength.Long);
      }

    }
    else if (eventArgs.Error != null)
    {
      Logger.console(eventArgs.Error.Message);
    }
  };

  webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(attachmentPath));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer to this issue in case anyone else runs into it. I'm not sure if this is just a Monodroid bug or there is something else at play that I'm unaware of. To solve this issue take these two lines of code:

```
intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(attachmentFile));
intent.SetType(mimeType);
```

and condense to this:

```
intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(attachmentFile), mimeType);
```

I can't believe this worked. After spending almost two days on this I thought just to condense the code and could not at first figure out why it started working.